# Return path location for File in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, file, firefox

Yes, I am trying to drag and drop a file into my browser. I would like to then take the path for that file, and assign it to some variable in my JS code.

Below is my failing attempt to make it work. Please show me some example to achieve this.

```
<body>

<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    output = [];
    var source = evt.dataTransfer.files();
    for (i=0, f; f=source[i], i++){
        outpush.push(source[i])
    }
    console.log(outpush[0]);
}

window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
  handleFileSelect(e);
},false);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

- `evt.dataTransfer.files()` is not a function. It should be replaced with `evt.dataTransfer.items`.
- Your *for loop* is invalid, it should be changed from

  ```
  for (i=0, f; f=source[i], i++){
      outpush.push(source[i])
  }
  ```

  ...to...

  ```
  for (i=0; i < evt.dataTransfer.items.length; i++){
      output.push(source[i]);
  }
  ```

  - The part inside the brackets of the for loop is invalid.
  - You are trying to add the file to `outpush`, which does not exist. You should be adding the file to the array `output`, which you did create.
- You can not get the path of the file, as JavaScript has no access to the host computer (for security reasons). You can still manage the file though using `source[`*`index`*`].getAsFile()`.

---

## Corrected code

**I have provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/cufxL968/).**

```html
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();
      output = [];
      var source = evt.dataTransfer.items;
      for (i = 0; i < evt.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
        output.push(source[i]);
      }
      console.log(output[0]);
    }

    window.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
      e = e || event;
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
      e = e || event;
      e.preventDefault();
      handleFileSelect(e);
    }, false);
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```